# Create recordio file for linear regression

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using AWS Sagemaker to run linear regression on a CSV dataset. I have made some tests, and with my sample dataset that is 10% of the full dataset, the csv file ends up at 1.5 GB in size.

Now I want to run the full dataset, but I'm facing issues with the 15 GB file. When I compress the file with Gzip, it ends up only 20 MB. However, Sagemaker only supports Gzip on "Protobuf-Recordio" files. I know I can make Recordio files with im2rec, but it seems to be intended for image files for image classication. I'm also not sure how to generate the protobuf file.

To make things even worse(?) :) I'm generating the dataset in Node.

I would be very grateful to get some pointers in the right direction how to do this.

Comment: are you using the built-in algo (aka Linear Learner) ?

Comment: @Julien - Yes, I do

Comment: Did you try [csv-protobuf-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-protobuf-stream) to convert csv to protobuf using Node and then use in training?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it but the module is broken and unmaintained. I'm getting a handful of errors when trying it.

Answer (score 1):

This link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-preprocess-data-transform.html has useful information if you are willing to use a Python script to transform your data.

The actual code from the SDK is https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/amazon/common.py

Basically, you could load your CSV data into an NDArray (in batches so that you can write to multiple files), and then use https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/amazon/common.py to convert to Recordio-protobuf. You should be able to write the buffer with the Recordio-protobuf into a file.

Thanks